# How to trim and match in a MongoDB aggregation?

Tags: mongodb

I want to do a MongoDB aggregation which first matches with some values and then groups them. But the field which has to be matched has values in the DB which have leading and trailing spaces in some of them. I want to first trim and then match them. How do I do that?

```
async AggregateTypes(_, { retailer_type }) {
  const matchCond = {};
  if(retailer_type) matchCond.cidm_retailer_type = {$in: retailer_type}
  res = await collection.aggregate([
    { 
        $match: matchCond 
    },
  ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [$trim](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/trim/) operator in `$expr` expression match condition,

```
if(retailer_type) {
  matchCond = { 
    $expr: { 
      $in: [
        { $trim: { input: "$cidm_retailer_type" } }, 
        retailer_type
      ] 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I pair these with other matches also which use the $in operator?

Comment: yes you can but for this type of cases, for direct match you can put condition outside $expr.. if i am going wrong  then please show some example will give more accurate solution..